# How to activate the ReactionButton box on long press?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, button, emoji

I'm trying to make the ReactionButton box (from the **[flutter_reaction_button](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reaction_button)**) activate or should I say pop up on its own when I hold the like button and not just change the child widget of the GestureDetector() widget:

My code:

```
GestureDetector(
                  onLongPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelected = true;
                    });
                  },
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLiked == true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: _isSelected == true
                      ? _showEmojieReaction()
                      : FaIcon(
                          _isLiked == true
                              ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidThumbsUp
                              : FontAwesomeIcons.thumbsUp,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                ),
```

My ReactionButton method:

```
_showEmojiReaction() {
    final emojis = Provider.of<PostsProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return ReactionButton<String>(
      onReactionChanged: (String? value) {},
      reactions: emojis.emojisList,
      initialReaction: Reaction<String>(
        value: null,
        icon: const FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.thumbsUp,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
      boxElevation: 10,
      boxPosition: Position.TOP,
      boxPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 13.0),
      itemScale: 0.5,
      boxColor: Colors.white,
      boxRadius: 10,
      boxDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      itemScaleDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    );
  }
```

The bool variables:

```
bool _isSelected = false;
  bool _isLiked = false;
```

What I got so far:[image]

Comment: please explain your question more specifically.

Comment: `hold the like button and not just change the child widget` mean not to effect by holding, then remove `onLongPress` .